# Detect video encoding using Adobe air

Tags: apache-flex, video, encoding, air, adobe

I am developing an AIR application that will allow the user to upload videos using the app. I want to allow only files with .mp4 extension (I have done this) But I want to allow only files with MPEG-4 encoding and not h.264 encoding.

Is there a way I can check the encoding of a video file. Help here is highly appreciated as I an running late on my deadlines.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: H.264 is one of the encoding profiles defined in the MPEG-4 specification.  Do you want to allow streams encoded in the Advanced Simple Profile (MPEG-4.2) and prohibit streams encoded by the Advanced Video Coding profile (MPEG-4.10)?

Comment: Hi I am not familiar with MPEG version. I am using mac and I right click and select "get info" to view the video file details. In the get info when the coded says MPEG-4 those videos work for me. When the codec section says h.264,aac this video does work for me in my app. When i open the h.264 codec video in VLC and export it to MPEG-4 it then works and the "get info" now shows "MPEG-4" in the new video. Excuse me if I sound dumb. But hope I gave enough info.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some of renaun's work might be of use?

I'm assuming there is some code in this project that might allow you to detect whether it's h.264 or not.

http://renaun.com/blog/code/qtindexswapper/